# Using Categories in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, objc-category

I have a file called `ViewMessages.m` which is becoming quite verbose. I'd like to refactor and put part of my methods into a separate file. It seems that Categories are the right way to go, so I've created a `Category` on `ViewMessages` called `DataEngineViewMessages`

It created 2 files, `DataEngineViewMessages.h` and `DataEngineViewMessages.m`

**My Question:** Do I need to `#import "DataEngineViewMessage.h"` in my original `ViewMessage.h` or `.m` in order to access my new methods?

Comment: If you're accessing the methods from the category in the original class (instead of the opposite, which is normal), then I'd say you don't have a good design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not into the .h file. The category header should import `ViewMessages.h`, and *if required* the category header should be imported into `ViewMessages.m`. This prevents any kind of circularity.

Usually you want to differentiate between category methods that should be public (defined in a header perhaps like `ViewMessages+DataEngine.h`) and category methods that are for internal use (defined in a header perhaps like `ViewMessages+Private.h`). The former shouldn't be included by `ViewMessages` and the latter should (again, in the .m file).

Comment: what exactly does "if required" mean? If I write methods in DataEngine.m that I want to use in ViewMessages.m?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Usually those methods would be private, but not always.

Comment: In the case that the methods are private, I can simply declare my methods in dataengine.h, write them in dataengine.m, and then import dataengine.h in viewmessages.m to use them? As a side question, will @properties defined in viewmessage.h be accessible in dataengine.m? Thanks

Comment: Yes, and yes. Because dataengine.h imports viewmessages.h

Comment: I just tried implementing the above design, however I'm unable to access the properties of ViewMessage.h in DataEngine.m even though I'm #import "ViewMessage.h" in DataEngine.h

Comment: do I have to create an instance of ViewMessage every time I want to access one of the properties of ViewMessage.h?

Comment: You need to access them through `self.` (you don't create a new instance, the category methods are called on an instance)

Answer (score 1):

Any code that calls the methods will raise a compiler warning if the compiler can't see the method definition. They may also raise an error if the compiler can't figure out exactly what to do about the return type and you're expecting it to be an atomic C type.

In terms of keeping the external interface untouched, you can probably just add a `#import` for your category methods at the bottom of the main class's header file.